# Get all Pages and their Page layout in a web app using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server, page-layout, web-application

I want to get all pages and their layout using powershell in a given web application

Answer (score 1):

```
filter Get-PublishingPages {
$pubweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($_)
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$pubweb.GetPublishingPages($query)
}

Get-SPSite -WebApplication http://sharepoint -Limit All | Select -ExpandProperty AllWebs | Get-PublishingPages | select Uri, Title, @{Name='PageLayout';Expression={$_.Layout.ServerRelativeUrl}}| Format-List
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606341/powershell-to-list-all-pages-with-their-layout-across-the-rootweb-and-all-subweb

Comment: its not working http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/9472/nadeem-yousuf

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Thanks for your time... ! But some other script worked...!